# How to make exclusive folder to specific user in windows 10?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-explorer, file-permissions

I have some photos/files that I don't want anyone to see it.
We have a shared family PC which I am the adminstrator, I want to set a folder only accessible by my username on windows, Is that possible?
So no one can check its content except me and the applications I use.

Comment: What edition of Windows is this? Home? Professional? In general, if the administrator account and user acounts have passwords, then any folder that's in a user's "My Documents" (just "Documents" on Windows 10) will not be accessible to any other user without the owner explicitly granting permission.

Comment: If those are users there isn't any way to accomplish what you want without an encrypted volume.